# Simplified Chromatography - will this work?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, chromatography

I am interested to separate a sample matrix via a method very similar to chromatography. The reason I am asking about this is because I am planning to integrate this method with my SERS application.

This is what I have in mind: 
[image]

- A droplet of sample is placed at position X.
- 50/50 Methanol/water is dropped at position Y.
- The chromatography plate is outlined as red. It is made of silica gel.
- This plate is placed flat on a table.

*Assuming:*

- The solvent does not overflow to the sample drop area.
- The solvent can only travel via the direction of the arrow
- The solvent will dissolve the sample while it is travelling.

**Will this actually work?**

Comment: What does 'work' mean in this context?  Are you asking if there will be a chromatographic separation?

Comment: Why not just do TLC, since that is pretty much what you have described the set-up for?

Comment: @ringo Because TLC requires evaporation chamber and a bunch of other stuff. I am building a special type of stripes that cost less than a dollar for my SERS application.

Comment: @Lighthart Yes. I am referring to sample separation

Comment: You can do TLC without a vapor chamber.  The separation isn't as good.